# Strange StageWebView

Tags: facebook-graph-api, flex4, webview

I am experiencing strange StageWebView behavior. I am opening a **StageWebView** in a view that is pushed in **navigator**, I have a close button in the view that Pops up the view from navigator..

The first strange thing the StageWebView doesn't go with view popped up, it is quite obvious as the StageWebView is getting added in the current **stage**.

Then I tried to set the **webView.stage=null**, that actually removes the webView, but it gives error as one parameter required.

Then I tried with **webView.dispose()** with try catch surroundings bingo, it worked. BUT now when again I push the view the StageWebView doesn't appear..

Anyone with any idea, can help me out..

Thanks..

Comment: Some code would certainly help to understand your problem, cause from your description it is kinda hard to guess what exactly happens at what stage. Also, you might wanna check out this adjusted [StageWebView](http://www.judahfrangipane.com/blog/2011/01/16/stagewebview-uicomponent/).

Comment: Why don't you use the visible property to show and hide the StageWebView?

Answer (score 0):

`Dispose()` literally disposes the webview meaning you need to recreate the object again in order to use it again.

`var webViewObject = new "Object"` (can't remember the class off top but you get the idea)

You're on the right track though